# Use \foreach within animate inline in Beamer class throws error

Tags: beamer, foreach, animate

I encounter an issue with the following code and must admit that I was able to find trick on the forum for now.

```latex
\begin{frame}{Title}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,poster = first, controls]{1}
   \foreach \x in {a,b}{
     \includegraphics[scale=1]{../figures/fig-\x}%
       \newframe
    }
\end{animateinline}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

When I unflatten the list, there is no problem. However, the \foreach loop throws an error (`Undefined control sequence`).

I can't find any workaround.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, welcomme. Please add a compileable code.

Answer (score 1):

Pkg `animate` has its own looping device, `\multiframe`. It should be used instead of external looping commands, such as `\foreach`, with a `\newframe` in the loop body.

For parameterizing the file name argument of `\includegraphics` with non-numeric values ("a", "b", "c"), use pkg `pgf`'s array-like expression in combination with `\multiframe`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\def\imgID{{"a", "b", "c"}}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[loop, controls]{1}
  \multiframe{3}{i=0+1}{  % i = <init. val.> + <incr.>
    \pgfmathparse{\imgID[\i]}%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-\pgfmathresult}%
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```